# How to schedule refresh using python script in power BI?

Tags: office365, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have written a python script with a database query. After designing reports and publishing those on services (I used a personal gateway for scheduling the refresh) I am not getting refreshed reports. Not even after refreshing in desktop. How can I achieve that the reports are refreshed properly?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported on Power BI currently, which I find disappointing. My workaround is to export an xlsx from my Python. I run the python script exporting an excel file every day via task scheduler or crontab that overwrites the one from the previous day. My Power BI dataset points to that file and is refreshed daily on services without errors as the data source from PBI's point of view is a simple excel file.

Not ideal but my workaround. I hope scheduled refresh for Python data sources will soon be implemented.